# Where does SSMS save user created templates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Does SSMS save these to a file location or are they managed internally thru SSMS?  If there is a location where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created one. It seems to put it in

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\Templates
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure why my search didn't pick it up.

Comment: In case you're using 17.x SSMS standalone, it's a little different: %appdata%\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\14.0\Templates